# Problem with different indexing in pandas and xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing, xlsxwriter

Here is the code which works fine:

```
import pandas as pd


# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1,1,1,1, {'type': '3_color_scale'}) ##CHANGES THE COLOR OF SECOND ROW

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

This creates below output.

[image]

My question is,  Is it possible to include the Header `Data` in the pandas indexing? I want to start indexing from 1st row. So Header `Data` should have index 0. It is useful because in `xlsxwriter` 1st row has index 0.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly index is an object and default index starts from 0. You can swift it by typing:

```
df.index += 1
```

As for the header's index name pandas method to_excel takes an argument which is called index_label. So your code should be:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})
df.index += 1

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_conditional.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index_label='0')

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Apply a conditional format to the cell range.
worksheet.conditional_format(1,1,1,1, {'type': '3_color_scale'}) ##CHANGES THE COLOR OF SECOND ROW

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]